# what is the difference between free pages and zeroed pages, and which is more important?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I understand that zeroed pages are "zeroed out". But I don't understand, why is that preferable.
The importance sorted:
zeroed > free > standby > modified

Comment: They're different things.  For security reasons pages that may be reassigned to a different process need to be zeroed, but pages that are "free" within a given process do not need to be zeroed.  Precisely how this all works depends on the particular OS you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Zeroed pages can be used as a substitute of freed pages but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to use page which have been zeroed out for security reasons. Indeed, a user-mode processes must be given initialized page frames to prevent them from reading a previous process’s memory contents.